# HTML fields are not returned when using ADO API reporting/workitemrevisions

Tags: azure-devops, agile

I am using the following API :
https://{instance}/{proj}/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?api-version=4.1&types=User Story

This is returning all fields on ADO instance user story except System.Description and Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria (both HTML type). Does this API not return HTML fields or am I missing something?

I tried using API: https://{instance}/{proj}/_apis/wit/workItems/{workitemNumber} and am able to fetch these fields with PAT token so I know this is not an access issue. The documentation does not mention that HTML fields will not be returned. This is part of existing integration and was working fine earlier but for some reason these fields are not returned now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the given API does not return HTML fields. It only provides non-HTML fields since send HTML fields as well will make the response very large.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).